# How to use a custom shell while SELINUX is enabled, via direct login and via ssh

Tags: selinux, sshd

**Summary:**

I want to be able to log in to a machine that has SELINUX=enforcing as a user with a custom shell both over ssh and from the login screen at the machine directly. Currently the problem is that I can only log in from one method or the other, never both.

**Details:**

I have a user called `user` using an alternative shell at `/othershells/user-shell` and I've recently enabled SELINUX.

When logging in as `user` directly on the machine and it works fine as long as I set the context of the file to `login_exec_t`.

However, if I try to log in from another machine over ssh I get permission denied. When inspecting the audit.log I see the following:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/sshd from getattr access on the file /othershells/user-shell.
*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests  ***************************

If you believe that sshd should be allowed getattr access on the user-shell file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do allow this access for now by executing:
# grep sshd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
Target Context                system_u:object_r:login_exec_t:s0
Target Objects                /othershells/user-shell [ file ]
Source                        sshd
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/sshd
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          <Unknown>
Source RPM Packages           openssh-server-5.3p1-122.el6.x86_64
Target RPM Packages           file /othershells/user-shell is
                              not owned by any package
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.7.19-307.el6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     S3CDN-94C691108F1B-133-FifthMA
Platform                      Linux S3CDN-94C691108F1B-133-FifthMA
                              2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 21 19:29:05
                              UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   2
First Seen                    Tue Mar 20 17:09:59 2018
Last Seen                     Tue Mar 20 17:19:47 2018
Local ID                      c824c859-26b9-4d82-b818-0aef394df449

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1521566387.844:731): avc:  denied  { getattr } for pid=25466 comm="sshd" path="/othershells/user-shell" dev=dm-1 ino=130776 scontext=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:login_exec_t:s0 tclass=file

type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1521566387.844:731): arch=x86_64 syscall=stat success=no exit=EACCES a0=7f7fc2f2747f a1=7ffcb9baf120 a2=7ffcb9baf120 a3=1999999999999999 items=0 ppid=8963 pid=25466 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm=sshd exe=/usr/sbin/sshd subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
```

So it wants me to set the context to `sshd_t` but if I do that, then directly logging doesn't work. There's no way to have multiple contexts so I checked to see if there were generic contexts that would allow multiple uses of a file and found these two:

```
public_content_t

public_content_rw_t
```

Neither of which worked because they're read, and read/write respectively. I'd need some kind of public read/write/execute.

I took a look at the booleans available in https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-sshd_selinux/ and none of them worked either.

Is there anything I can do to be able to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. The context I wanted was `shell_exec_t`